# Windows Phone parsing xml with a strange node (like <media:group>)

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, xml-parsing

i have an issue... i'm parsing an xml in this way:

```
public MainPage(){
InitializeComponent();
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
Uri url = new Uri("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/my_channel/uploads/?alt=rss&prettyprint=true", UriKind.Absolute);
client.OpenReadAsync(url);
}
public void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e){
try{
    var xml=XDocument.Load(e.Result);
    var results=from row in xml.Element("rss").Element("channel").Elements().Where(element=>{
        return(element.Name.LocalName == "item");
    })select row;
    List<MioVideo> videoList = new List<MioVideo>();
    int totalevideo = 0;
    foreach (var result in results){
        XElement title=result.Elements().Where(element => {
            return element.Name.LocalName == "title";
        }).FirstOrDefault();
        XElement description = result.Elements().Where(element =>
        {
            return element.Name.LocalName == "description";
        }).FirstOrDefault();
        XElement mylink = result.Elements().Where(element =>
        {
            return element.Name.LocalName == "link";
        }).FirstOrDefault();
        String id_video = mylink.Value;
        id_video = id_video.Substring(31,11);
        videoList.Add(new MioVideo(title.Value, description.Value, mylink.Value,"http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+id_video+"/hqdefault.jpg"));
        totalevideo++;
    }
    listavideo.ItemsSource = videoList;
}
catch (Exception c){
    MessageBox.Show(c.Message);
}
}
```

I want to parse another node, but it has a name like , and i don't know how to parse it and retrieve the value inside yt:duration.

Can someone heml me???

---

in other word, my xml is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<rss xmlns:app='http://purl.org/atom/app#' xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007' version='2.0'>
    <channel>
        <description></description>
        <atom:id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/mychannel/uploads</atom:id>
        <lastBuildDate>Tue, 03 Jan 2012 12:24:02 +0000</lastBuildDate>
        <category domain='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'>http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video</category>
        <title>Uploads by MyChannel</title>
        <image>
            <url>http://www.youtube.com/img/pic_youtubelogo_123x63.gif</url>
            <title>Uploads by MyChannel</title>
            <link>http://www.youtube.com/profile?user=MyChannel#p/u</link>
        </image>
        <link>http://www.youtube.com/profile?user=MyChannel#p/u</link>
        <atom:link rel='self' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/MyChannel/uploads?alt=rss&amp;start-index=1&amp;max-results=25'/>
        <managingEditor>MyChannel</managingEditor>
        <generator>YouTube data API</generator>
        <openSearch:totalResults>75</openSearch:totalResults>
        <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
        <openSearch:itemsPerPage>25</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
        <item>
            <guid isPermaLink='false'>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/Qt6wF29Ytzo</guid>
            <pubDate>Fri, 23 Dec 2011 12:10:17 +0000</pubDate>
            <atom:updated>2011-12-23T13:22:34.000Z</atom:updated>
            <category domain='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'>http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video</category>
            <category domain='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat'>Comedy</category>
            <category domain='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat'>Natale</category>
            <category domain='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat'>paolo</category>
            <category domain='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat'>labati</category>
            <category domain='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat'>auguri</category>
            <category domain='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat'>comicità</category>
            <category domain='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat'>italiana</category>
            <category domain='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat'>mychannel</category>
            <category domain='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat'>MyChannel</category>
            <title>mio video</title>
            <description>Tanti auguri di Buon Natale!!!</description>
            <link>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qt6wF29Ytzo&amp;feature=youtube_gdata</link>
            <author>MyChannel</author>
            <gd:comments>
                <gd:feedLink href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/Qt6wF29Ytzo/comments' countHint='0'/>
            </gd:comments>
            <media:group>
                <media:category label='Commedie' scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat'>Comedy</media:category>
                <media:content url='http://www.youtube.com/v/Qt6wF29Ytzo?version=3&amp;f=user_uploads&amp;app=youtube_gdata' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' medium='video' isDefault='true' expression='full' duration='17' yt:format='5'/>
                <media:content url='rtsp://v4.cache4.c.youtube.com/CigLENy73wIaHwk6t1hvF7DeQhMYDSANFEgGUgx1c2VyX3VwbG9hZHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp' type='video/3gpp' medium='video' expression='full' duration='17' yt:format='1'/>
                <media:content url='rtsp://v3.cache5.c.youtube.com/CigLENy73wIaHwk6t1hvF7DeQhMYESARFEgGUgx1c2VyX3VwbG9hZHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp' type='video/3gpp' medium='video' expression='full' duration='17' yt:format='6'/>
                <media:description type='plain'>Tanti auguri di Buon Natale!!!</media:description>
                <media:keywords>Natale, paolo, labati, auguri, comicità, italiana, mychannel, MyChannel</media:keywords>
                <media:player url='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qt6wF29Ytzo&amp;feature=youtube_gdata_player'/>
                <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Qt6wF29Ytzo/0.jpg' height='360' width='480' time='00:00:08.500'/>
                <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Qt6wF29Ytzo/1.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:00:04.250'/>
                <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Qt6wF29Ytzo/2.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:00:08.500'/>
                <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Qt6wF29Ytzo/3.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:00:12.750'/>
                <media:title type='plain'>Paolo Labati - Buon Natale</media:title>
                <yt:duration seconds='17'/>
            </media:group>
            <yt:statistics favoriteCount='1' viewCount='432'/>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

and i need to retrieve the value from yt:duration and media:thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

To parse elements which aren't in the default namespace, you must create a `XNamespace` object. At the top of your XML doc, it should have the namespace for media.

get the XML from your link:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/my_channel/uploads/?alt=rss&prettyprint=true
```

at the top, it will have a namespace defined.

```
xmlns:media="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

Copy this namespace into your project like so: (you could parse it off in code each time)

```
protected XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

Then, an example of how to use it:

When an element you're expecting to have will use the media: tag, do the following

```
IEnumerable<XElement> links= responseElement.Elements(ns + "link");
```

Comment: sorry but can you make an example with my code?
i don't understand, i'm new in wp7

Comment: i retrieve an error on: responseElement, it doesn't exist in the current context